# How to change values within a stateful widget class from a different class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stateful widget `LetterButton()`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text(widget.caption),
      onPressed: onChanged,
      color: colors[currentIndex],
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
    );
  }
```

In my main.dart file I declare an array of LetterButtons

```
  List<LetterButton> buttonArray;
```

which I initialize and fill during `initState()` via the method

```
void makeButtons() {
    for (var letter in alphabet) {
      buttonArray.add(
        LetterButton(letter),
      );
    }
  }
```

The buttons in the list are then displayed in the UI

```
Wrap(
     children: buttonArray,
   )
```

How can I change the value of `currentIndex` (an `int` in 
`class LetterButtonState extends State<LetterButton>`) or otherwise change all the buttons to the same color from main.dart?

NOTE: I asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61048128/how-to-simultaneously-set-a-property-on-multiple-buttons/61049434#61049434) a few days ago, but the answer was a little above my current knowledge, as are responses I've seen to similar Q's here on SO. I have a little understanding of callbacks, and experimented a little with the provider package, but there's such a variety of answers and info available online that it's hard for me to even know what I don't know to be able to answer my question :-)

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/50554101

Comment: Just to be sure. You need to change only the currentIndex, am I right?

Comment: Yes, colors[] is a list of Colors so when the index changes the buttons’ colors should change.

Answer (score 0):

Create stateful widget with state as public access, so that you can access outside of the package and provide key to constructor. So that you can refer key and get can get state to change value. See the following example

```
class LetterButton extends StatefulWidget {
  LetterButton({GlobalKey key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  LetterButtonState createState() => LetterButtonState();
}

class LetterButtonState extends State<LetterButton> {
  int value = 0;

  //this public method is to update int value
  setValue(int value) {
    setState(() {
      this.value = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(value.toString()),
    );
  }
}



//In Main.dart
GlobalKey<LetterButtonState> _buttonStateKey = GlobalKey();

//while creating widget
LetterButton(key:_buttonStateKey)

//in onTapCallback you can call to update value
_buttonStateKey.currentState?.setValue(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just send your created function to new class by parameter and the new class should be Constarcter with Function lThen you can call the function from a new class.